# Mockito.lenient does not return expected result

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMyStuff{
    @Mock
    private Worker worker;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        Mockito.lenient()
                .when(worker.doWork("some stuff", "some other stuff", new Date()))
                .thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.lenient()
                .doReturn(true)
                .when(worker).doWork("some stuff", "some other stuff", new Date());
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //quick test to see if mock works.
        final boolean isDone = worker.doWork("zzz", "qwerty);
        System.out.println("isDone: " + isDone);//i want isDone to be true
    }
}
```

The `Mockito.lenient()` method does not seem to be working because it is not returning `true`. How do I make the method `Worker.#doWork()` return `true` no matter the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:
       `when(Worker.doWork(anyString(),...).thenReturn(true)`
However, I think the code you posted have some problems. "doWork" method seems like taking two String and one Date object. In the test method you should give proper inputs to "doWork" to see results.